# Clear limited files from browser cache

Tags: php, browser-cache

Is it possible to refresh the browser cached data when necessary via PHP code? 
I have a fairly complex web application and I am using browser caching to speed up loading time/performance of pages.

How can I retain the advantages of browser caching, but still have the browser refresh the files when necessary?
There are two sets of files - some are library files which need not change, and some are local, which change infrequently. I need to clear the browser cache only for local files conditionally.
Is that possible?

I have this code:

```
header("Expires: Tue, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT");
header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");
```

And this clears entire cache; any pointers in this direction would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT"); 
header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT"); 
header("Cache-Control: private, no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate"); 
ini_set('session.cache_limiter', 'private');
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");
```

Comment: Will you please explain how "private" cache_limiter will help?

Comment: The cache limiter defines which cache control HTTP headers are sent to the client. These headers determine the rules by which the page content may be cached by the client and intermediate proxies. Setting the cache limiter to nocache disallows any client/proxy caching. A value of public permits caching by proxies and the client, whereas private disallows caching by proxies and permits the client to cache the contents.

Comment: Okay, great. Thanks! looks like this would be something I am looking for.